# unable to upload a excel file into Azure Storage Blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload an excel file into Azure storage Container but unable to do so. Instead of uploading the excel file it's uploading the container name itself. there is a code below I tried. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.IO;

namespace Console_Workstation
{
    public class Azure_Storage_Connection
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorageAccount"].ConnectionString;
            string localFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceFolder"];
            string destContainer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["destContainer"];
                            
            // Connect to container
            BlobContainerClient blobContainer = new BlobContainerClient(connstring,destContainer);
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
    
            // Connect to Blob into the container
            BlobClient blob = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(destContainer);
    
            // Upload Local file
            blob.Upload(@"C:\Users\AbdulHameedM\Desktop\LocalFolder\Mapper.xlsx");
        }
            
    }
}
```

PFB the screen shot instead of Mapper.xlsx excel file it is showing inputExcel(Container Name)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When getting the `BlobClient` you can specify the name of the blob. You are doing:

`BlobClient blob = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(destContainer);`

so the blob is named after the value of `destContainer`.

You are pobably looking to do:

`BlobClient blob = blobContainer.GetBlobClient("Mapper.xlsx");`

That will put a blob named "Mapper.xlsx" in the container named after the value of `destContainer`.